# why does netty client return Observable<Observable<ByteBuf>> instead of Observable<ByteBuf>?

Tags: java, netty, reactive-programming, rx-netty

tutorial / examples show:

```
Observable<HttpClientResponse<ByteBuf>> httpGet =
                                          RxNetty.createHttpGet("http://xxxx");
Observable<Observable<ByteBuf>> byteBuffers =
                                     httpGet.map(HttpClientResponse::getContent);
```

i understand that bytes may come in chunks therefore i understand the need of `Observable<ByteBuf>`.

but why `Observable<HttpClientResponse>`? why not just 1 single `HttpClientResponse` that provides `Observable<ByteBuf>`? or maybe in fact it is just a `Single<HttpClientResponse>` wrapped in `Observable` to make api more fluent? but in this case is there some documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is essentially a `Single<HttpClientResponse>`. Since these APIs were created before `Single` was introduced in RxJava, they do not use `Single`